# Is there a multinomial version of the DeMoivre-Laplace theorem?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, multinomial-theorem

The DeMoivre-Laplace theorem says that in the limit for large $n$, the distribution tends to a Gaussian.

Can we say the same for multinomials? Can someone give me a reference as well?

Comment: Each "component" of a multinomial distribution is a binomial distribution...

Comment: @Ian Interesting... Can you please clarify? It's not really my field.

Comment: I mean that a multinomial distribution is defined by a number $n$ and $k$ probability values. A sample from it is $k$ numbers that sum up to $n$. Each of these numbers separately is binomial distributed, so each of the 1-marginal distributions of a multinomial distribution has an asymptotic normal distribution. The more interesting thing is the joint distribution, since they are coupled (in particular, all $k$ components always sum to $n$).

Comment: If you are still interested, the answer to your question is yes. See the the 'Local Theorem' in section 2, page 85 of Gnedenko - "The Theory of Probability"